# Android EditText Control Scrollbar

Tags: android, scroll, android-edittext

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/textbox"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true" />

    ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.display)).setKeyListener(null);
```

the EditText serves as some kind of log box, text is appended to it at some events.

I need the EditText to be scrolled to the right at all times, I mean the scrollbar should be positioned to the maximum right and so the most recent text is visible.

I cant seem to get it done, not sure how to read the current position of the scrollbar and adjust it accordingly.

I've tried playing with EditText.setScrollX() though even setScrollX(10000) didnt have any effect.

Comment: a wild guess: try `editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length()-1);`

Comment: works, great thanks. not sure if it's possible to accept your comment as an answer though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with

`editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length()-1);`